# How to open task manager in remote desktop using C# programmatically

Tags: c#, window, remote-desktop, sendkeys

I am using the below code to open task manager in Remote desktop connection (mstsc). But this code opens task manager in my local machine:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
Process[] rmdProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName("mstsc");

int pid = rmdProcess[0].Id;
User32.SetForegroundWindow(rmdProcess[0].MainWindowHandle.ToInt32());
IntPtr hdcSr = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessById(pid).MainWindowHandle; 

SendKeys.Send("^+{ESC}");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the machine name. Plus you want **taskmgr** not **mstsc**.

Change this:

```
Process[] rmdProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName("mstsc");
```

...to this:

```
Process[] rmdProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName("taskmgr", "<insert-machine-name-here");
```

### More

- [Check out this rather nice example on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.machinename(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: To use this example you must first start at least one instance of the process on a remote computer.So this did not work.Can you suggest something else.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code and it worked:

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + tasklist /s <RemoteMachineName>/u <username>/p <password>);
        Process.StandardOutput StreamReader.
        procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
       procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
       procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
 System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
      proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
      proc.Start();
```